# Getting date in '2015-08-04'{"Y-M-D"} format. How to change the specified date format into UTC format?

Tags: javascript, date, knockout.js, utc

I am getting the date format in this way:- `'2015-08-04'` using knockout.js. How to change the specified date format into UTC format like `"2015-08-08T19:20:18+00:00"`?

Like in Javascript we are having date function like `date.getDate()` to get the particular date from the UTC format?

But after getting the date in the above specified format using the knockout.js, I am not able to get the particular date like `date.getDate()` using JavaScript.

Is there any function in knockout.js to get a date or month or only year from the specified date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Date object, just pass it in through `new Date()`:

```
new Date('2015-08-04')
-> Tue Aug 04 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

If you want a UTC string, do the above and call `toISOString()` on it:

```
new Date('2015-08-04').toISOString()
-> "2015-08-04T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: I will try it. Thank you